# Density of the cannonball problem packing

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, surfaces, pi, polygons

The [Cannonball problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannonball_problem) states that you can make a rectangle and a pyramid with a rectangle base using $4900$ cannonballs (with radius $1$).

> The question is, what is the density of the packing in the rectangle?

---

I think: the packing can be written as:

$$\frac{\text{total area of the cannonballs}}{\text{total area of the rectangle}}$$

Now, a rectangle is just a special type of a regular n gon, the area of such a gon is equal to:

$$\frac{ns^2\cot(\pi/n)}{4}$$

And the area of circle with radius $1$ are given by:

$$\pi$$

So:

$$\frac{\pi\cdot\text{number of cannonballs}}{\frac{1}{4}\cdot n\cdot\left(\text{number of cannonballs per side}\right)^2\cot(\pi/n)}$$

Now, I got:

$$\frac{\pi\cdot4900}{\frac{1}{4}\cdot4\cdot70^2\cot(\pi/4)}=\pi$$

But that is impossible because this means that the cannonballs are taking more space than the area of the rectangle in the first place.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A circle occupies $\frac \pi4$ of the square it is inscribed in.  If the cannonball has radius $1$ the square has side $2$, which is the factor $4$ you are missing.   You took $s=1$

Comment: Do you mean that $s=2\cdot\text{number of cannonballs per side}$?

Comment: Yes. I was just thinking of one ball in a square. If you have $70$ on a side the square is $140 \times 140$